# How to watch a model from a directive in the context of its source scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to watch a model from within a directive.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
          modelToWatch: '@'
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch(scope.modelToWatch, function(val) {
              // do something...
           });
       }
    };
]})

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
       foo: 'val'
    };
}]);

<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div my-directive model-to-watch="obj.foo"></div>        
</div>
```

The above works fine.

However, I encounter a problem when there is an intermediary scope between the actual owner of the model and the directive.

I used another controller to demonstrate the scenario below:

```
.controller('AnotherController', ['$scope', function($scope) {}])

<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-controller="AnotherController">
        <div my-directive model-to-watch="obj.foo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the case for above, I could look up the $parent tree to find the scope which owns the property I want to watch using the code below:

```
...

link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   var contextScope = scope;

   // find for the scope which owns the property that we want to watch
   while (contextScope != null && contextScope.hasOwnProperty(attrs.modelToWatch)) {
       contextScope = contextScope.$parent;
   }

   // use the scope found to watch the model
   if (contextScope != null) {
      contextScope.$watch(scope.modelToWatch, function(val) {
          // do something...
      });
   }
}
```

Additional problem, however is if the modelToWatch is a complex expression (e.g: "tableParams.filter().shop_id" then the hasOwnProperty cannot be relied upon.

Is there an easy way to watch a model in the context of its owner scope? Or is it's possible to watch a model even from a prototypal child?

Or can I pass scope as a parameter, so at least I don't have to look for it...

```
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
    modelToWatch: '@',
    sourceScope: '=', // don't know how to do this..
}
```

Note: I need to use isolate scope

As suggested by @pixelbit, I tried using the $eval to find the correct scope

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   var contextScope = scope;

   // find for the scope which owns the property that we want to watch
   while (contextScope != null && contextScope.$eval(attrs.modelToWatch) != undefined) {
       contextScope = contextScope.$parent;
   }

   ...
}
```

Works for most cases except when the modelToWatch expression actually evaluates to undefined.. There is an ambiguity whether the modelToWatch doesn't exist in the current scope (meaning it's not the owner) or the modelToWatch expression just happens to evaluate to undefined.

Comment: Why are you binding the model name with @ instead of = two way binding?

Comment: modelToWatch will hold the model name itself. e.g: model-to-watch="obj.foo" I'm watching the 'obj.foo' model not 'val' which is its value

Comment: You don't need to watch 'obj.foo' on the parent scope. Pass it to your directive and watch it on that scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/MGI84zJXYhBciG9zmDTZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an isolated scope - you can inherit scope instead.  Also to address complex expressions, you can use scope.$eval to evaluate the model and find the appropriate scope. Once you've evaluated the model, return it from a watched function:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: false,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch(function() {
               return scope.$eval(attrs.modelToWatch);
           }, function(val) {
              // do something...
           });
       }
    };
]})
```

If you *must* to use an isolated scope, then watch a function and return the model:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
           modelToWatch: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch(function() {
               return scope.modelToWatch;
           }, function(val) {
              // do something...
           });
       }
    };
]})
```

Comment: I already used $parent before. But the problem is I'm unsure to which $parent the modelToWatch belongs.. Sometimse it belongs to the immediate $parent sometimes it's one level higher, etc.. That's why my main problem is to find which $parent the modelToWatch belongs

Comment: If modelToWatch is undefined, then it should behave correctly as one would expect if the model is undefined.  There is no need to find the owning scope, unless that is also part of your requirement for a solution.

Comment: unfortunately, i still need to watch it nonetheless. it may evaluate to undefined at first

Comment: i'll try refactoring my directive to not use isolate scope

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a controller directly inside your directive :

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      modelToWatch: '='
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(scope.modelToWatch, function(val) {
          // do something...
       });
   },
   controller: 'MyController'
  };
]})

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    foo: 'val'
  };


}]);

<div my-directive model-to-watch="obj.foo"></div>
```

That way, when you will call your directive, your controller will be instanciated first, then the link will be executed, sharing the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch a function instead:

```
scope.$watch(function() { 
        return scope.modelToWatch; 
    }, function(val) {
        // do something
});
```